# "Axel Jump" in jazz and figure skating - question about etymology

Tags: etymology

I'm sorry, I didn't find a "dance" stackexchange, but it's a question about etymology for me. We know that the "axel jump" in figure skating was named that because it was invented by a person called [Axel Paulsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axel_Paulsen). How was the name "axel" given to the jazz turn/jump? I am not sure if Axel Paulsen emulated what he saw in jazz dance on the ice, or if jazz dance emulated what Axel Paulsen did. If Paulsen came up with the figure skating jump due to what he saw in jazz, was it called something else before him?

Answer (score 2):

Figure skating is older than Jazz Dance as a discipline. Although the African origins of Jazz Dance are ancient it did not become a recognised dance form with named moves and choreography until the early 20th century when white society took it up and added white styles to it.
On the other hand [Brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/sports/figure-skating) says that the first book on figure skating was published in 1772. Obviously this would not have been anything like modern figure skating but the Brittanica entry also mentions the revolutionary contribution of Jackson Haines based on ballet and formal social dance to figure skating in the 1860s.

Given this history it can be seen that figure skating was well established when [Axel Paulsen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axel_Paulsen) was born in 1855 and he was both a speed skater and a figure skater. Also Haines had greater success with his freer style in continental Europe than his native US so would have influenced Paulsen.

Again according to the Brittanica entry Paulsen first demonstrated the turn named after him in 1882 at the first international competition

The development of both modern figure skating and modern jazz dance took place in the early 20th century but by then the skating world was already aware of the Axel Turn and, of course, its inventor (who died in the 1930s). Jazz Dance must have adapted the Axel Turn from figure skating, not the other way around. Remember that the jazz dance version is different from the figure skating version because skaters can build up much more momentum before they jump. This isn't a criticism of dancers, it's just physics.

Comment: Hmm, since I was only looking for etymology, this is a good response. And I guess it makes sense that Paulsen more than likely didn't look at African dances for inspiration in the late 1800s (he might have, but we don't know). Just off a tangent, it's entirely possible that the African dance equal of an axel turn already did exist much before Axel Paulsen - but it might have been named an "axel" because when white society took it up, it looked like an axel jump from figure skating.

Comment: @learning That's possible but I don't know whether it would have been possible to do a full Jazz Dance Axel in the spaces and on the surfaces that were available to African and Afro-American dancers in the 19th century and earlier. I suspect that you would need a good quality wooden stage or a formal ballroom floor given over to display dancing to make it work properly. I can't be sure, the only sort of dancing I've ever done seriously is stick Morris and English longsword.